# Change href depending on php response

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to change the href of morestorieslink depending  on the data received from mysql database i.e. if there is no row returned from server then the href for DOM element morestorieslink should change

I am using this for changing the href value

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("morestorieslink").href="select.php?<?php echo $selecturl?>=<?php echo $select; ?>&select=Continue";
                    </script>
                    <?php
                    echo "Url Changed";
                }
```

In this case javascript doesn't work but the echo is displayed, I also tried embedding javascript inside php echo.
Thankyou

Comment: should you not `echo` your script too?

Comment: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
......javascript goes here...
echo "</script>";` like this?

Comment: As i also mentioned above I tried that but still the same @SandeepNayak

Comment: Has your element id = "morestorieslink" being created before this statement?

Comment: So when you write the above code the link is not changed right? If yes, then first `echo $selecturl;` and `echo $select;` before script and check what they returns and let me know.

Comment: yes i did that @Arpita

Comment: yes all the variables are returing a value @KaushaMehta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     // wait for dom to finish loading properly.
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        document.getElementById("morestorieslink").href="select.php?<?php echo $selecturl?>=<?php echo $select; ?>&select=Continue";
     });
 </script>
 <?php
       echo "Url Changed";
 }
```

Put this at the **last** of your page make it a point that **no java script is executed after this**. Rest all looks good.

Hope that helps.

**Note :**

the href you mentioned will append to the exsisting url.

Also check that $selecturl or $select is not null  and isset.

You can also check the page source to check wether the link is generating properly or not (using Firebug in mozilla)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator. Something like:

```
<?php echo $select ? $selecturl.$select :  $otherURL;?>
```

I assumed your url is changing based on value of $select